# IDA : trap call

Tags: ida

i'd like to improve support for Atari ST in IDA.
To do this, I'd like to know if there is a way to handle trap #1 (gemDos), trap #2 (gem), trap #13 (bios) and trap #14 (xbios)  used this way

```
MOVE.W #3, (-SP)
TRAP #13 ; call Bconout (bios func 3)
```

Is it possible to auto detect the function number put on the stak before a trap call ? and so add the right comment ?

I know some plugins do it on request only (ex: press CTRL+SHIFT+T to launch the detect), it'll be a valid option if automatic detection isn't possible/accurate.

thanks for any hint !